# Angular 9 and rxjs - wait for message event after postMessage

Tags: rxjs

I am new to rxjs and not sure how to implement the follow logic. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

**Background**

I am going to implement the communication between host website and an iframe in it with postMessage. Since postMessage is one-way only, I would like to implement the logic to wait for 'response' by myself when a message is sent from host website to iframe.

I have a sync function called `send(message)` to invoke the postMessage to send message to iframe. Then I would like to have another function with the follow logic.

```
public async sendAndWait(message): Promise<responseObj> {
    // 1. create an observable to wait to message event with timeout

    // my first thought is as follow but I feel like it does not work
    // fromEvent(window, 'message')
    //  .pipe(timeout(timeoutInMs))
    //  .subscribe(event => {
    //    console.info(event);
    //  });

    // 2. run `send(message)` function

    // 3. do not finish this function until timeout or receive event in the previous subscription.
}
```

When I use the function, I would like to have

```
let response = await sendAndWait(message);
```

Not sure if it is possible to implement? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot stop code execution in JS (using `Async-Await`, a `Promise` object is returned behind the scenes. so that the code is never waiting)

Consider implementing it in the following way:

```js
let response: responseObj;

function main(): void {
  sendAndWait(MESSAGE_OBJECT).subscribe(x =>  response = x)
}

function sendAndWait(message): Observable<responseObj> {
  send(message)
  return fromEvent(window, 'message')
    .pipe(
      timeout(timeoutInMs),
      first()
    )
}
```

Or optionally returning `Promise`:

```js
async function sendAndWait(message): Promise<void> {
  send(message)
  const response = await fromEvent(window, 'message')
    .pipe(
      timeout(timeoutInMs),
      first(),
      toPromise()
    )
}
```

Comment: Hi Rafi, thank you for your suggestion. The only thing I am not sure is your code send the message and then setup the listener to message event. 

Since postMessage runs between the host website and the iframe in the same browser, could it happen that before the listener is set up, the response already emitted so that the listener will never receive a message?